# Python Flask: Unable to Initialize SQLite Database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, flask, command-line-interface

I'm following the Flask tutorial found here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/. I've followed Steps 0-4 but can't understand Step 5 (Creating the Database); I've read and added the relevent functions to my flaskr.py script, so that it currently looks like this:

```
# all the imports
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__) # create the application instance :)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from this file , flaskr.py

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    """Initializes the database."""
    init_db()
    print('Initialized the database.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    app.run()
```

The tutorial then says that the database can be initialized by calling:

```
flask initdb
```

Running this command yields:

```
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: No such command "initdb".
```

From following the tutorial thus far, I don't have a `flask` script in my application directory. I've also done some more reasearch and found this resource: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/, which states that a virtual environment comes with this flask script, but my virtual environment doesn't have this file. I've verified this by navigating to my root directory and using:

```
find . -name flask
find . -name flask.py
```

However, neither of these commands returns any matches. As I am relatively new to Flask, I might be missing something simple here; can someone explain what I am missing and offer workarounds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure, can you include in your question the output of `pip show Flask`? Do it in your virtualenv (of course).

Comment: @skytreader: `pip show Flask` yields: `Name: Flask
Version: 0.12
Summary: A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
Home-page: http://github.com/pallets/flask/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/neil/Desktop/flaskr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Jinja2`

Answer (score 1):

Pure educated guesswork here. But in the code you've shown you have the following:

```
@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    """Initializes the database."""
    init_db()
    print('Initialized the database.')
```

I think that should be

```
@app.cli.command()
def initdb():
    ...
```

Notice that there is no argument to the decorator and that the function was renamed to match the command you are invoking in the command line.

A cursory glance at the Flask and click docs does not show that you can pass a string to the decorator and invoke it as labeled.

Comment: I've attempted your suggestions, but the same error occurs when running the app with `flask initdb`:  `Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Error: No such command "initdb". ` Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: More guesses. Keeping the changes introduced by my answer, do you export the environment variables `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_DEBUG` before running `flask initdb`? [See here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/packaging/#tutorial-packaging)

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error as I worked through the tutorial. I found that I had opened a new terminal window to work in why the server ran in another. I fixed the issue by running the export command again:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
```

Then:

```
flask initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`python -m flask initdb`

Another thing to check, if you're going through the tutorial: is your `__init__.py` file in the correct location? It should be in the second level flaskr directory, not in the top-level directory.